# ResourceNotFoundException android kitkat

Tags: android, exception, crash, resources

I have a Recyclerview. in it's adapter, this is what i have:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    //gradient is my arraylist that contains resource IDs. these are set in my fragment class

    int res = gradient.get(position);
   holder.parent.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Application.getAppContext(), res));

   }
```

and in my fragment i pass these resource IDs to adapter:

```
    final ArrayList<Integer> gradients = new ArrayList<>();


    gradients.clear();


    gradients.add(R.drawable.gradient);
    gradients.add(R.drawable.gradientgray);
    gradients.add(R.drawable.gradient2);

    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(gradients) //it has a constructor that gets the arraylist and sets it to the arraylist in adapter class.
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

it works on android > 4.4 but it crashes on android 4.4 with ResourceNotFound Exception.

**EDIT:**
Stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: example.myapp, PID: 1652
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070074
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:698)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:456)
    at example.myapp.ui.dashboard.DashboardRecycler.onBindViewHolder(DashboardRecycler.java:62)
    at example.myapp.ui.dashboard.DashboardRecycler.onBindViewHolder(DashboardRecycler.java:22)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:446)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
```

One of drawables: (All of them are the same but their colors differ)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<gradient
    android:endColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:startColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:type="linear" />

<corners
    android:radius="0dp"/>
```

Drawables are like this but just their colors are different.

Also i tried setting drawable without arraylist in recyclerView's adapter (like R.drawable.gradient instead of arraylist.get(position)) and it worked fine. but using arraylist it works fine on higher android versions.
I know invalidating caches is not related but that didn't help too.

Comment: please post stacktrace

Comment: Also, what are the actual drawables? Post an example of one that is triggering your crash.

Comment: added more details. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out!
some drawables were like "gradient2.xml (mdpi)" so i deleted them and created a new xml file for them.
this happened because i was copy pasting xml files to create a new xml file.